# Library usage in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, libraries

How many libraries can I use in a single Kotlin project? I mean can I implement more than one library in my app? I have seen a lot of libraries and couldn't figure which one to use? Starting from the [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library to jetpack and so on...

Comment: Usually yes, you can use any number of libraries you want.

Comment: ANKO is obsolete and should not be used. Using at least some of the Jetpack libraries is pretty much required if you want to avoid using deprecated code in Android. If there is an upper limit of libraries you can use, it's in the thousands and not something you'll realistically have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can realistically use as many libraries as you want. To find the libraries that you want, I would recommend knowing exactly what you want for your application. Here is a good list of useful libraries. https://github.com/mcxiaoke/awesome-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use more than a few libraries I strongly recommend the use of a dependency management tool like e.g. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). It adds some complexity to use these tools, but in the long run it will save you a lot of headaches.